# VB .net: How to put a value on a checkbox (databese: MS Access)

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, checkbox, vbscript

I just need a little help for my homework. I did my best think about the logic but it's too late. So basically, this is what I need to do : 


If I'll check the checkbox 1 it will automatically input "100" on the second column of my datagridview and also if I'll check checkbox 2 it will also input "50" on my 3rd column.

**[ ] Fee1** (checkbox1) = $100
**[ ] Fee2** (checkbox2) = $50


The output should look like this: 

StudentFeeTableGridView

**Name| Fee 1|  Fee 2** 

Jack  |    0    |  50 
   Jill   |  100  |  0 
John  |  100  |  0 
Jose  |    0    |  50 


Thank you so much guys for helping! I owe you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `DataGridView.SelectionMode=FullRowSelect` and use `CheckedChanged` event. With code below, values will be inserted to cells in selected row:

- For 1 checkbox:

`If (Fee1.checked=True) Then dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Fee1").Value="100"`

- For 2 checkbox:

`If (Fee2.checked=True) Then dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Fee2").Value="50"`

**Note**: `.Cells("Fee1")` and `.Cells("Fee2")` must be valid column name in DataGridView.

Comment: woah! Thank you so much! That's awesome.

Comment: `dataGridView1.` - changed to valid name of your datagridview?

Comment: Change `[" "]` to `(" ")`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just change the cells name into numbers like .Cells(2) and .Cells(3) and it worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: Right. You can use cell index or column name (not header text).